# Generate serial resulted from: current date + (max_number + 1) in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

"max_number" is the max integer number from serials that includes current date in MS SQL table

ex: Serial: '2018122210' consists of date: 2018/12/22 and number: 10.

the next serial in this day will be: 2018122211
and first serial in next day will be: 201812231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    MaxNum VARCHAR(20)
)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        MySeq = 1,
        MyDate = FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd'),
        MaxNum = FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd')+'01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        MySeq = MySeq +1,
        MyDate = FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd'),
        MaxNum = MyDate+RIGHT('00'+CAST(MySeq+1 AS VARCHAR(10)),2)
        FROM CTE
            WHERE MySeq < DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
)
INSERT INTO @T
SELECT
    MaxNum
    FROM CTE

SELECT
    MaxId = FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd')+
                RIGHT('00'+CAST(
                MAX(CAST(REPLACE(MaxNum,FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd'),'') AS INT))+1
                AS VARCHAR(10)),2)
    FROM @T
        WHERE FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd') = LEFT(MaxNum,8)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i want to get max inserted number part based on current date for each entered row

Comment: @MohammedAbdelwahab I've updated the answer to take the Seq Based on the Max+1. Try now